# Is there any index/statistics reflecting the likelihood to have items stolen in a given country?

Tags: security

The likelihood to have items stolen greatly differs between countries. For example, if I leave my phone somewhere unattended in a subway station for one hour, one would expect it to be stolen if it is in Paris, whereas it's near impossible to be stolen if it is Tokyo. By the same token, getting pickpocketed in Athens is part of the tourist experience while it's pretty much unheard of in Seoul.

Is there any index/statistics/etc. reflecting the likelihood to have items stolen in a given country? That would help me appropriately adjust my expectations and how careful I should be regarding my belongings. Ideally I would like to have at list of countries along with the level of "theft" likelihood.

Comment: I think you are a bit optimistic about Tokyo. It is less likely to be stolen, not unlikely.

Comment: Is it stolen if you leave something behind at a subway station ?

Comment: @Max https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theft_by_finding

Answer (score 2):

Depends.  Some crime happens regardless, and other crimes target tourists specifically because they're not always aware of local methods.

So statistically, just looking at theft, there are numerous statistics on [theft rates by country](https://www.theglobaleconomy.com/rankings/theft/). (source: UN office on drugs and crime).

Then, the World Economic Forum produces a report annually : [The Travel & Tourism Competitiveness Report](http://www3.weforum.org/docs/WEF_TTCR_2019.pdf) which looks at a number of aspects of countries and regions for tourism, including crime levels.